# Rails 3 error in Safari only - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with auth_token = ):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In following Railscast #274 to get reset password working in my Rails 3 app, I am experiencing a weird issue in Safari. If I run my app in Heroku I get the following error when I go to my root:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with auth_token = ):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:39:in `lookup_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:32:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:54:in `logged_in?'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
```

If use Firefox and Chrome (in incognito mode) it works. In Safari, I found that if I get the error, I can make it go away by navigating to `/logout`. Then the page renders perfectly.

Here's my route for `/logout` and `root`:

```
match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
root :to => "users#new"
```

Here's my `destroy` action in `sessions_controller`:

```
def destroy
  reset_session
  cookies.delete(:auth_token)
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You successfully logged out"
end
```

My `application_controller`:

```
protected

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= lookup_user
  end

  def lookup_user
    if session[:user_id]
      User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    elsif cookies[:auth_token]
      User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token])
    end
  end
```

And lastly, here's my `new` action in `users_controller`:

def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.profile = Profile.new
    if logged_in?
      redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    end
  end

**What I've tried:**

*To alter the `new` action to delete cookies with the following:*

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.profile = Profile.new
  if logged_in?
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
  elsif
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
  end
end
```

*The rake task below, as suggested in the [Railscast comments](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=comments):*

```
namespace :user do
  desc "Rebuild Auth-Tokens"
  task :rebuild_auth_token => :environment do
    User.transaction do
      User.all.each { |u|
        u.generate_token(:auth_token)
        u.save!
      }
    end
  end
end

(I ran this with `heroku run rake user:rebuild_auth_token`)
```

Neither seems to have worked. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anytime you regenerate the user :auth_code's you will need to delete your cookies for that domain. In a production, you should not regenerate :auth_codes and you will never have this issue, unless users edit their cookies.

In addition I have posted a response on the railscast.com authentication (revised) solution so Ryan can take a look at it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added in your code to my `lookup` method and it seems to crash my app. I tried with/without `return nil`, and stripped away everything but `cookies.delete(:auth_token)` but that served the same error I was getting above.